# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for array<string>

Tags: apache-spark-sql

*I want to import the output data into the mysql database, but the following error occurs, I will not convert the array to the desired string type, can help me?*

```
 val Array(trainingData, testData) = msgDF.randomSplit(Array(0.9, 0.1))
    val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(labelIndexer, word2Vec, mlpc, labelConverter))
    val model = pipeline.fit(trainingData)
    val predictionResultDF = model.transform(testData)
    val rows = predictionResultDF.select("song", "label", "predictedLabel")
    val df = rows.registerTempTable("song_classify")
    val sqlcommand = "select * from song_classify"
    val prop = new java.util.Properties
    prop.setProperty("user", "root")
    prop.setProperty("password", "123")
    sqlContext.sql(sqlcommand)
      .write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yuncun", "song_classify", prop)
    sc.stop
```

*Here is the console output*

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for array<string>
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getJdbcType$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:148)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$jdbc$JdbcUtils$$getJdbcType$2.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:148)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
```

***I want to store the following data in the mysql database***

```
+---------+-----+--------------+
|     song|label|predictedLabel|
+---------+-----+--------------+
|   [一吻天荒]|    1|             2|
|  [有一点动心]|    1|             2|
|   [有你真好]|    1|             2|
|  [永远不分开]|    1|             2|
|[我要我们在一起]|    2|             2|
|  [后来的我们]|    2|             2|
|     [喜欢]|    2|             2|
|     [夜车]|    2|             2|
|   [寂寞疯了]|    2|             2|
|     [拥抱]|    2|             2|
|   [方圆几里]|    2|             2|
|   [时间煮雨]|    2|             2|
|    [爱上你]|    2|             2|
|     [献世]|    2|             2|
|   [说散就散]|    2|             2|
+---------+-----+--------------+
```

**But the first column is an array, so the program is getting an error**

**Can you help me propose a change plan? Thank you**

Comment: The error says clearly that you can't store array on the database you need to explode the array column or convert to a string before writing.

Comment: @ShankarKoirala I'm a newbie. I don't know how to convert an array to a string. This is where I really can't.Can you help me, thank you

Comment: yes yes ,thank you very much!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to remove the `columns` with `array` type before writing to the databases.

You can create a `string` with comma separated for the column type `array` as

```
val datafrme = ??

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

dataframe.withColumn("song", concat_ws(",", $"song"))
// then write to database
    .write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc("url", "song_classify", prop)
```

`concat_ws` creates a string the values in an `array` with delimiter provided.

Hope this helps!

Comment: works as a charm. one note worth mentioning is even though you got strings values in the array, te final output would be just one huge string, ie i expected to got the conversion as: ```"\"string1\",\"string2\""``` but instead it converted it (and i believe this is completely OK) into ```"string1,string2"```