# Spark DataFrame write to JDBC - Can't get JDBC type for struct <date:int, day:int...>?

Tags: java, apache-spark, exception, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I am new to spark, and was trying to write a dataframe to db2 table.  The error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for struct <data:int, day:int, hours:int, minutes:int, month:int, seconds:int, time:bigint, timeZoneOffset:int, year:int>
```

My database schema is

```
localId <-- Integer type
effectiveDate <-- Timestamp
activityDate <-- Timestamp
inDate <-- Timestamp
outDate <-- Timestamp
```

I created a POJO class for my db table which goes like this

```
public class StowageTable {
    private long localId;
    private Date effectiveDate;
    private Date activityDate;
    private Date inDate;
    private Date outDate;
    //setters and getters
}
```

I then basically read a csv which has the same schema as the db table as follows:

```
JavaRDD<String> dataFromCSV = javaSparkContext.textFile(fileURL);
//The I create a JavaRDD of the POJO type
JavaRDD<StowageTable> dataToPOJO = dataFromCSV.map((Function<String,  StowageTable) line -> {
    String[] fields = line.split(",");
    StowageTable st = createNewStowageTable(fields);
    return st;
});
//converting the RDD to DataFrame
DataFrame stowageTableDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataToPOJO, StowageTable.class);
//call jdbc persister
persistToTable(stowageTableDF);
```

My `persistToTable(DataFrame df)` method is as follows:

```
private void persistToTable(DataFrame df) {
    Class.forName("")//driver here
    //skipping a few lines for brevity
    df.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url, table, connectionProperties);
}
```

I found a few solutions here: [Spark DataFrame write to JDBC - Can't get JDBC type for array<array<int>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45563340/spark-dataframe-write-to-jdbc-cant-get-jdbc-type-for-arrayarrayint)
and [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't get JDBC type for array<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50201887/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-cant-get-jdbc-type-for-arraystring)
but **could not** find any which addresses a date-time data type issue. Please suggest me some solution to it. I am on spark 1.6.3.

Comment: It says can't get JDBC type for `struct` Can you execute `df.printSchema()` and see if the columns are correctly mapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could not find any answer yet, and figured out a solution for myself in the meantime so here is the basic idea. If the database has datatype as Timestamp, then you have to use Timestamp in the POJO of the object and then convert that Timestamp to spark's structtype.

Comment: you can use java.sql.Date as well

Comment: As @Hasson said using java.sql.Date did worked.